# Generating URL's that fill forms on my site

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a asp.net web forms page where admins can search by user last name and then select them and approve or deny their access to the site. When users request access, an email is sent out informing admins. I want to be able to send a link that populates the page with that users info for easier approval. How would I approach this?

Comment: Does the user enter any info into the system? It sounds like they would, since an admin is searching in the system for the new user. Would the data not already be in your user table?

Comment: Yes the user enters info into the system, and yes the web forms page allows the admin to search for the user from the user table. But what I am asking is if someone requests access, a url would be generated so that the form would be filled out and the admin doesn't have to search the user table.

Comment: Did you try adding the user ID as a URL parameter and using that to preload the form when the page loads?

Comment: Ill try that.. do you mean the site.com?param=whatever ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the user has to enter his data into a form, simply save that to the database. A common way to do this could be to have a user table with a user ID, and a flag or status code stating that the record is inactive and needs administrator attention.

From here, the web app should send a link to the administrator with the user ID embedded in the URL. It would look something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/ActivateUser.asp?id=1234
```

When the admin user clicks on the link, the server responds with a page with that user's information pre-filled in the form ready for the admin to edit in his browser.

The admin could then press a button to active the user, edit that flag or status code, whatever the implementation details are.

This is a very common task and you can view the source code for one of any number of open-source message boards or CMS packages for examples. They are typically written in PHP as opposed to ASP and much more complex, but the general idea is the same.